# check last blank line of HTTP request using perl chomp

Tags: perl, webserver, httprequest, chomp

I'm pretty new to Perl. My Perl program is getting the HTTP request message from browser, I want to detect the last blank line.

I was trying to use `$_ =~ /\S/`, but which doesn't work:

```
while (<CONNECTION>) {
  print $_;
  if ($_ =~ /\S/) {print "blank line detected\n"; }
}
```

the output is

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
blank line detected
Host: xxx.ca:15000
blank line detected
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686; rv:5.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/5.0
blank line detected
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
blank line detected
Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.7,zh-cn;q=0.3
blank line detected
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
blank line detected
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
blank line detected
Connection: keep-alive
blank line detected
Cookie: __utma=32770362.1159201788.1291912625.1308033463.1309142872.11; __utmz=32770362.1307124126.7.3.utmcsr=google|utmccn=(organic)|utmcmd=organic|utmctr=Manitoba%20Locum%20Tenens%20Program; __utma=70597634.1054437369.1308785920.1308785920.1308785920.1; __utmz=70597634.1308785920.1.1.utmcsr=google|utmccn=(organic)|utmcmd=organic|utmctr=leung%20carson
blank line detected
```

---

---

---

I was trying to use chomp(), which does not work for me too:

```
  while (<CONNECTION>) {
    chomp(); 
    print "$_\n";
    if ($_ eq "") {print "blank line detected\n"; }
  }
```

the output:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: xxx.ca:15000
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686; rv:5.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/5.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.7,zh-cn;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
Connection: keep-alive
Cookie: __utma=32770362.1159201788.1291912625.1308033463.1309142872.11; __utmz=32770362.1307124126.7.3.utmcsr=google|utmccn=(organic)|utmcmd=organic|utmctr=Manitoba%20Locum%20Tenens%20Program; __utma=70597634.1054437369.1308785920.1308785920.1308785920.1; __utmz=70597634.1308785920.1.1.utmcsr=google|utmccn=(organic)|utmcmd=organic|utmctr=leung%20carson
```

Thanks in advance~

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To detect lines with nothing but whitespace,

```
while (<CONNECTION>) {
  print $_;
  if ($_ =~ /\S/) {print "blank line detected\n"; }
}
```

should be

```
while (<CONNECTION>) {
   print $_;
   if ($_ !~ /\S/) {print "blank line detected\n"; }
}
```

Or for short,

```
while (<CONNECTION>) {
   print;
   if (!/\S/) {print "blank line detected\n"; }
}
```

The reason

```
while (<CONNECTION>) {
   chomp(); 
   print "$_\n";
   if ($_ eq "") {print "blank line detected\n"; }
 }
```

might not work is because HTTP header lines end with \r\n. You'd need

```
while (<CONNECTION>) {
   s/\r?\n//; 
   print "$_\n";
   if ($_ eq "") {print "blank line detected\n"; }
 }
```

Comment: `HTTP header lines end with \r\n`, so Linux also add '\r' besides '\n'?

Comment: @draw, Linux doesn't add anything. HTTP clients (e.g. browsers) use \r\n to end lines, as per the protocol.

Comment: @ikegami, thanks. How do you know the new line is `\r\n`? I failed to find it on `w3.org`. Actually, I'm curious about the structure of header line.

Comment: @draw => the gory details can be found here: http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt (just search for CRLF)

Comment: Using \r\n is potentially fragile. Better to be explicit and use \015\012. See the section on newlines in "perldoc perlport" for details.

Comment: @davorg, Not at all. No need to kowtow to obsolete Macs

Answer (score 1):

I think you want:

```
/^\s+$/
```

for blank line detection.

Using /\S/ will detect NON-blank lines.

Better yet, use something like Net::HTTP or LWP to do the heavy lifting for you.  Some of the HTTP encoding issues are subtle.

Comment: `/^\s*$/` or the less redundant `/^\s*\z/` would be a bit more flexible than `/^\s+$/`.

Comment: @ikegami: This is not an arbitrary string, but rather part of a HTTP protocol message.  We are not going to be seeing an empty string here.

Comment: So you're saying it would hurt to use `/^\s*\z/`? Claiming that `/^\s+\z/` detects blank lines, on the other hand...

Comment: @ikegami: It is unlikely to hurt, but is also going to match lines even further away from the standard than mine does.  Really you should just ($_ eq "\r\n") and be done with it.